# How do I use an extension method in an ASP.NET MVC View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, extension-methods

How do I access an extension method in an ASP.Net MVC View? In C# I do

```
using MyProject.Extensions;
```

and I remember seeing an XML equivalent to put in a view, but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: Is this 'accessing' or 'referencing'?
[not picking nits - a question of transitioning from vb]

Comment: @justSteve what's the difference?

Comment: In my mind....referencing is the act of prepping the system for the actual utilization (accessing). We can't use a method of a different class until we've setup the reference.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In View:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyProject.Extensions" %>
```

Or in web.config (for all Views):

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Linq" />
    <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />

    <add namespace="MyProject.Extensions" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: I had to close the .aspx file in VS2008 and open the file again before Intellisense picked up the imported namespace.

Comment: Is it literally "MyProject.Extensions", or is it specific? So would mine be: <add namespace="BusinessLogic.ExtensionModule" />?

Answer (score 20):

For pages using Razor / WebPages, you can include a `using` directive in your .cshtml page.

```
@using MyBlogEngine;
```