# Can I use Extension Methods inline in an ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net, extension-methods, inline-code

Is it possible to do something like this inline in an ASPX page?

```
<%= Me.SomeExtensionMethod() %>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work properly. I'm receiving an error saying that "SomeExtensionMethod" is not a member of the current Page object. I've added the necessary `<%@ Import Namespace="..." %>` directive at the top of my page. This **Does** work in code-behind.

This isn't vitally important, but it would be good to know how to do in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try closing the `.aspx` page and opening it up again as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115834/how-do-i-use-an-extension-method-in-an-asp-net-mvc-view). If that improves things at all (e.g. enable intellisense) but doesn't solve it, please post any new errors you get.

You could also add the `Public` modifier to your `Module` or `class` definition. If you're using Modules, it really doesn't make sense to me that it would be required, but some discussion on [this forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/74834e18-548a-4160-9640-00d769ac27b0) indicates that it might help.

Comment: This worked! Like you, it really doesn't make sense to me, but adding the "Public" access modifier did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me! I did have to change my module to a Public scope and add an import to "Namespace.ModuleName".

Comment: Thanks - I used the `import` statement and it worked.

Answer (score 15):

Adding imports in the namespace works for me!

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Foo.FooFoo" %>
```

Comment: This here is the answer.  It's inaccessible because the class that contains the extension method is not Import-ed/'using'-ed automatically within the class generated for the ASPX.  Adding an Import/using clause in the code-behind doesn't help either because the code-behind is only the base class of the ASPX-class.

Comment: This works in combination with [Michael Haren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2074364/3002584).

Answer (score 1):

If it's working in the codebehind, add the namespace to the function call:

```
<%=MyNamespace.ExtensionFcn("hello, world") %>
```

I'd do this before I'd modify the web.config.