# Calling Public Method on WAPs

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm currently converting my `WSPs` application into `WAPs` for security purpose.
but I got some issue, I can't call the Public function on `aspx` source in `WAPs`, on `WSPs` `aspx` source and `WAPs` codebehind there's no issue.

Here's the function ;

```
namespace WAUGHI
 {
public static class PublicVar
{
    public static string Expurgate(this string TargetStr, int MaxLenght)
    {
     if (TargetStr.ToCharArray().Count() > MaxLenght)
        {
            return TargetStr.Substring(0, MaxLenght) + "...";
        }
        else return TargetStr;
    }
 }  }
```

the function cut the string if the string exceed the limit on define length.

calling the function like this on aspx source

```
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Categories").ToString().Expurgate(24) %>'
```

e.g.

```
string = "Hung Hang is not chinese, guess?"
```

the output is `"Hung Hang is not chinese..."`

Answer (score 0):

You are using an extension method (`Expurgate`) over a `string` type.

Be sure that your namespace `WAUGHI` is accessible from your page.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074268/can-i-use-extension-methods-inline-in-an-aspx-page)